# Selecting parent directory that is 2 or more levels higher in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My directory structure is:

/project

1. Login

   |1.1 js

   |1.2 db
2. Main

I have a script in db that sends information through AJAX and returns if it's an user or admin, I want to redirect to a page that is stored in Main but when  I select the parent directory like I do in HTML it tells me that the page was not found

I read that I have to change the paths and add the Main folder to it since the default configuration doesn't allow me to go through 2 levels or more, but I don't know where am I supposed to change it

HTML, project/Login/index.php

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username"><input class="input100" type="text" id="user" name="username" placeholder="username">
<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
<input class="input100" type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="password">
<span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
</div>

<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
<a class="login100-form-btn" id = "logBtn">
login
</a>
</div>
```

JS, project/Login/db/loginverify.js

```
$('#logBtn').click(function(event){ 
    user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"login.php",
        async: false,
        data: {user:user,password:password},
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'Admin'){
                window.location.href='../../Main/index.php';
             }
             else if(data == 'User'){
                window.location.href='../../Main/startemp.php';
             }else{
               alert("username or password invalid");
             }
        }
        });
    });
```

PHP, project/Login/login.php

```
<?php
/*Testing if it redirects, not a real login*/
$user = $_POST['user'];

if ($user == "Admin"){
echo "Admin";
}

else if ($user == "User") {
echo "User";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use generic solution from which you will not be needed to record any kind of project stucture `var url=window.location.href.split('/');var baseUrl = url[0] + '//' + url[2] + "/" `  . This `baseUrl` will give you the base Path and after that you can add you relative directory and file path eg. `baseUrl + "/Main/index.php"`  Note: If you any virtual directory or application path in your application base path then you should add `url[3]` in your `baseUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your project structure, I think your backing down one step too far with your redirect. Try with just:

```
window.location.href='../Main/index.php';
```

and

```
window.location.href='../Main/startemp.php';
```

That should get you to the right folder if the project structure is as you wrote.